# Unable to post message

Tags: google-adsense, error

I have Google AdSense on my web site and on every page I am getting the following error:

> Unable to post message to `http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net`. Recipient has origin `http://mywebsite.com`

What is it? Will it affect my revenue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541797/javascript-errors-from-google-adsense.